# $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ continuous, $f$ derivable in $(0,1)$, $f(0) = 0$, $|f'(x)|\le 1$, then $-\frac{1}{2}\le \int_0^1 f(x) dx \le \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, continuity

I need to show the following:

$f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ continuous, $f$ derivable in $(0,1)$, $f(0) = 0$, $|f'(x)|\le 1$, then:

$$-\frac{1}{2}\le \int_0^1 f(x) dx \le \frac{1}{2}$$

Well, the exercise said to me to use the mean value theorem, so, there exists $c\in [0,1]$ such that:

$$f'(c) = \frac{f(1)-f(0)}{1-0} = \frac{f(1)}{1}$$
and using $|f'(x)|\le 1$ we have:

$$f'(c) = f(1) \le 1$$

but I don't see how any of this relates to the integral. Maybe if I see the integral as the derivative of the antiderivative but I don't see how it helps.

Comment: You probably mean that $f$ is differentiable in $(0,1).$

Comment: Have you considered showing that $|f(x)|\le |x|$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$$\left\vert \displaystyle\int_0^1 f(x) \; dx \right\vert
\le \displaystyle\int_0^1 |f(x)| \; dx = \displaystyle\int_0^1 |f(x)-f(0)| \; dx $$

And now proceed with mean value theorem

Comment: $|f(x)-f(0)|=|f'\ (c)(1-0)|\le 1$? I don't see how that helps

Comment: $\left| \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0} \right| = |f^{\prime}(c)| \leq 1 \Rightarrow |f(x)| \leq \ldots$

Comment: @Shai $|f(x)|\le |f'(c)x| \le x$? Then $\int_0^1 x = \frac{1}{2}$?

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\left|\int_0^1 f(x) \,dx\right| &= \left|\int_0^1 (f(x) - f(0)) \, dx\right| \\
&= \left|\int_0^1 \int_0^x f'(t) \, dt \, dx\right| \leq \int_0^1 \int_0^x |f'(t)| \, dt \, dx\\
&\leq \int_0^1 \int_0^x |f'(t)| \, dt\, dx \leq \int_0^1 \int_0^x \, dt \, dx\\
&= \int_0^1 x \, dx = 1/2
\end{align}

Comment: $\int _{ 0 }^{ 1 } \int _{ 0 }^{ x } |f'(t)|\, dt\, dx$  is repetied twice ,apart from that nice solution +1

Comment: In order to use $\int_{0}^{x}f'(t)dt=f(x)-f(0)=f(x)$ you need the first expression to make sense. How do you know that $f$ has an integrable derivative?

Comment: @NikolaosSkout because $f$ exists? Is that not sufficient?

Comment: @MichaelTong, in order for the theorem $\int_{a}^{x}f'(t)dt=f(x)-f(a)$ to hold you need to have $f$ differentiable AND the derivative should be integrable (the last statement is not implied by the first one).